# Subversion Not Working?

Tags: android, svn, ssl, intellij-idea, android-studio

I am working with Android Studio 1.1.0 and while connecting SVN repository from Android Studio VCS i m getting error:

```
Subversion: (Accessing URL: https://url/svn/project_name) No appropriate protocol
(protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate) Please check Subversion
SSL settings (Settings | Version Control | Subversion | Network) Maybe you should
specify SSL protocol manually - SSLv3 or TLSv1
```

I Tried:

- *File -> Setting -> Version Control -> SubVersion -> General -> Uncheck all (or check all)*
- *File -> Setting -> Version Control -> SubVersion ->Network (switched All or SSLv3 or TLSv1)*
- *Cleared auth cache*
- *Invalidate Caches / Restart*

How do I resolve the error?

Comment: Your SVN client and the used server do not match, I assume one of them is very old and does only support insecure SSL/TLS protocols and ciphers. You can check the SVN using an [online ssl test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/). Test it and update the supported protocols and ciphers in your question.

Comment: i am using with android studio. And IntellijIdea contains plugin for subversion. SVN client is 1.7 this is not too old.

Comment: The first 1.7 release was in 2011 the last in 2014 - don't know ehich one you use. Anyway the SSL library used by SVN is your problem. Perform the ssl test on the SVN server as I suggested and look at the results...

Comment: @Robert thanks for your time as i am using IP address so test is not possible.If you have any SSL relation information then please share (URL) So that i can check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Setup SVN with `Command line client`. Check below.

[image]

- *Make sure SVN path is in File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Subversion -> Check use command line client. Specify svn.exe in path (located at C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin)*
- *Also Check -> Use system default subversion configuration directory (located at C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Subversion)*

[image]

Then Prompt for authentication shown. Enter your credential.That's All.

Comment: For this purpose TortoiseSVN command line client can be replaced with any svn client like https://sliksvn.com/download/.

Answer (score 2):

In my case on Mac, in Android Studio -> Preferences-> Enable SVN interactive mode, it asked for to trust SSL certificate and add it to login keychain and everything worked as before.